# Difference between S3 trigger events and eventbridge(AWS API call via cloudtrail)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, eventtrigger

My company has multiple lambdas, and several of our associates use eventbridge(AWS API call via cloudtrail) to trigger a lambda when an S3 file lands in a bucket, with "putobject", and "putobjectACL". Several others use S3 triggers that use "createObject*". These latter lambdas that use S3 triggers with createobject seem to be triggering for some files twice, so I was thinking of changing createobject to "put". Is it likely that createobject might trigger twice for some files? Is there one method that is safer or more reliable?

What is the difference between:

S3 triggers:

- PUT
- POST
- Objectcreated

vs

Eventbridge(AWS API call via cloudtrail):

- putobject